# React: How to mount all components on page?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to mount React components based on the HTML markup of a document rendered by a PHP framework and I can't find a way to achieve this.

Here is the HTML markup of my document:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <Foo bar="lorem"></Foo>
        <Foo bar="ipsum"></Foo>
        <Foo bar="dolor"></Foo>
    </div>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Foo component implementation (foo.js):

```js
const React = require('react');

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', {
      className: 'foo'
    }, `Hello ${this.props.bar}`);
  }
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

And here is my App implementation (app.js):

```js
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

require('./foo');

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('div'),
  document.getElementById('app')
);

module.exports = {};
```

I'm expecting React to recursively mount every components found inside the `#app` div but for some reason only the `#app` div is mounted resulting in the following markup:

```html
<div id="app">
    <div data-reactroot=""></div>
</div>
```

I can't put my fingers on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

So, in you app.js when you are rendering react DOM

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('div'),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In this case you are creating a div element and rendering it inside root div with id=app

In order to create multiple foo elements all you have to do is this

```
const Foo = require('./foo');

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Foo bar="lorem"></Foo>
    <Foo bar="ipsum"></Foo>
    <Foo bar="dolor"></Foo>
  </div>
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The thing is I don't know which components will be part of the app. This is exactly what composition (aka component-based approach) is about: you have no idea at compile-time what will be the content of your page. The content of the page is served by a server-side PHP framework based on the layout that the user creates on the back-office.

Comment: What I meant from the answer is that ```React.createElement('div'),``` is wrong as it will create div element and render. What you actually want to do I think is to grab elements which PHP script is sending and apply in place of that line.

Comment: you're most certainly right, my ReadDOM.render call is the culprit.